# How to get rid of repeated code using foreach loop in Laravel 4 ?

Tags: php, class, laravel-4, foreach, model

I've been struggling trying to figure it out how to get rid of repeated code using foreach loop in Laravel 4

Here is my original code
[image: Original]

I want to make it dynamically generate in the foreach loop instead.

Here is what I have now

```
public static function validator($input){

        $rules = array(

                'title'                  =>'required|max:100',

                foreach ( $export_types as $export_type ){

                'type_'.$export_type->id =>'required',
                }

                'exported_date'          =>'date|required' );

                $validator               = Validator::make($input, $rules);

        return $validator;
    }
```

I got this little error
[image]

- Can anybody tell me what I `missed` ? :(
- Can I use a foreach loop inside a `class` ?
- If not, what is the `possible` way to do it ?

Comment: You can use a for loop inside a class; but you can't use a for loop inside an array definition

Comment: Note that `$export_types` isn't defined anywhere either

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You're right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've put a `foreach` loop inside of an array. That's your problem.

Also I'm not sure where you got `$export_Types` from so with a suggested edit it's been replaced with `ExportType::all()`

Define each new item you want to define with your `foreach` by using `[]`

```
public static function validator($input){

    $rules = array(
            'title'         =>'required|max:100',
            'exported_date' =>'date|required' 
    );

    foreach(ExportType::all() as $export_type) {

       $rules['type_'.$export_type->id] = 'required';
    }

    $validator = Validator::make($input, $rules);

    return $validator;
}
```